# To use Azure LUIS with voice do i need to get the text first?

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I think the title explains my doubt.

I've tried before the Speech to Text feature from Azure.
The question is:
Is there a way to use the sound binary to Azure LUIS instead of the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, LUIS can accept speech input instead of text. LUIS provides [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-recognize-intents-from-speech-csharp?toc=/azure/cognitive-services/luis/toc.json&bc=/azure/cognitive-services/luis/breadcrumb/toc.json) on how to setup speech services. The tutorial is in C#, however it appears their GitHub repo has [samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples) in other languages, if of use.

Hope of help!

Answer (score 0):

if you are creating a speech bot,  here is a new approach.

so it leverages azure speech (TTS and SR), integrate with bot service in a more easy way

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/directline-speech-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0